# Easiest way to compare arrays in C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, compare

In Java, `Arrays.equals()` allows to easily compare the content of two basic arrays (overloads are available for all the basic types).

Is there such a thing in C#? Is there any "magic" way of comparing the content of two arrays in C#?

Comment: To everyone reading this, keep in mind that the accepted answer is using SequenceEqual. SequenceEqual not only checks if they contain the same data, but also if they contain the same data in the same order

Answer (score 362, accepted):

You could use [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal).  This works for any `IEnumerable<T>`, not just arrays.

Comment: This only works if they are in the same order though

Comment: `SequenceEqual` may not be a good choice performance wise, because its current implementation may fully enumerates one of its sources if they differ only by length. With arrays, we could check `Length` equality first, in order to avoid enumerating arrays of different lengths just to end-up yielding `false`.

Comment: @Frédéric, infact `SequenceEqual` will first compare the lengths, if both enumerables implement `ICollection`, see https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/SequenceEqual.cs

Comment: @quinmars, this answer was about .Net Framework, .Net Core was not existing in 2010. The relevant code is [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,920).  
Still it is a good thing to know this point has changed in .Net Core. But it stays true for the .Net Framework.

Answer (score 112):

Use [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal#System_Linq_Enumerable_SequenceEqual__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) in [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query).

```
int[] arr1 = new int[] { 1,2,3};
int[] arr2 = new int[] { 3,2,1 };

Console.WriteLine(arr1.SequenceEqual(arr2)); // false
Console.WriteLine(arr1.Reverse().SequenceEqual(arr2)); // true
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this throws for null arguments, so make sure to not assume that `new int[] {1}.SequenceEquals(null) == false`

Answer (score 33):

Also for arrays (and tuples) you can use new interfaces from .NET 4.0: [IStructuralComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.istructuralcomparable.aspx) and [IStructuralEquatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.istructuralequatable.aspx). Using them you can not only check equality of arrays but also compare them.

```
static class StructuralExtensions
{
    public static bool StructuralEquals<T>(this T a, T b)
        where T : IStructuralEquatable
    {
        return a.Equals(b, StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer);
    }

    public static int StructuralCompare<T>(this T a, T b)
        where T : IStructuralComparable
    {
        return a.CompareTo(b, StructuralComparisons.StructuralComparer);
    }
}

{
    var a = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    var b = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(b)); // False
    Console.WriteLine(a.StructuralEquals(b)); // True
}
{
    var a = new[] { 1, 3, 3 };
    var b = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    Console.WriteLine(a.StructuralCompare(b)); // 1
}
```

Comment: On large value type arrays, there is a performance hit in using these, because their current implementation will box each value to compare.

Answer (score 23):

`SequenceEqual` will only return true if two conditions or met.

1. They contain the same elements.
2. The elements are in the same order.

If you only want to check if they contain the same elements regardless of their order and your problem is of the type

> Does values2 contain all the values contained in values1?

you can use LINQ extension method `Enumerable.Except` and then check if the result has any value. Here's an example

```
int[] values1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int[] values2 = { 1, 2, 5 };
var result = values1.Except(values2);
if(result.Count()==0)
{
   //They are the same
}
else
{
    //They are different
}
```

And also by using this you get the different items as well automatically. Two birds with one stone.

Keep in mind, if you execute your code like this

```
var result = values2.Except(values1);
```

you will get different results.

In my case I have a local copy of an array and want to check if anything has been removed from the original array so I use this method.

Answer (score 21):

For **.NET 4.0** and higher you can compare elements in array or tuples via using [**StructuralComparisons**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.structuralcomparisons(v=vs.110).aspx) type:

```
object[] a1 = { "string", 123, true };
object[] a2 = { "string", 123, true };

Console.WriteLine (a1 == a2);        // False (because arrays is reference types)
Console.WriteLine (a1.Equals (a2));  // False (because arrays is reference types)

IStructuralEquatable se1 = a1;
//Next returns True
Console.WriteLine (se1.Equals (a2, StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer));
```

Answer (score 20):

If you would like to handle `null` inputs gracefully, and ignore the order of items, try the following solution:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static bool ItemsEqual<TSource>(this TSource[] array1, TSource[] array2)
    {
        if (array1 == null && array2 == null)
            return true;
        if (array1 == null || array2 == null)
            return false;
        if (array1.Count() != array2.Count())
            return false;
        return !array1.Except(array2).Any() && !array2.Except(array1).Any();
    }
}
```

The test code looks like:

```
public static void Main()
{
    int[] a1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    int[] a2 = new int[] { 3, 2, 1 };
    int[] a3 = new int[] { 1, 3 };
    Console.WriteLine(a1.ItemsEqual(a2)); // Output: True.
    Console.WriteLine(a2.ItemsEqual(a3)); // Output: False.
    Console.WriteLine(a3.ItemsEqual(a2)); // Output: False.
   
    int[] a4 = new int[] { 1, 1 };
    int[] a5 = new int[] { 1, 2 };
    Console.WriteLine(a4.ItemsEqual(a5)); // Output: False 
    Console.WriteLine(a5.ItemsEqual(a4)); // Output: False 
    
    int[] a6 = null;
    int[] a7 = null;
    int[] a8 = new int[0];

    Console.WriteLine(a6.ItemsEqual(a7)); // Output: True. No Exception.
    Console.WriteLine(a8.ItemsEqual(a6)); // Output: False. No Exception.
    Console.WriteLine(a7.ItemsEqual(a8)); // Output: False. No Exception.
}
```

Comment: Great answer.  Wondering how I'd extend this to two dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 12):

For unit tests, you can use `CollectionAssert.AreEqual` instead of `Assert.AreEqual`.

It is probably the easiest way.

Answer (score 8):

For some applications may be better:

```
string.Join(",", arr1) == string.Join(",", arr2)
```

Answer (score 7):

Assuming array equality means both arrays have equal elements at equal indexes, there is the [`SequenceEqual` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3232755/1178314) and the [`IStructuralEquatable` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3234749/1178314).

But both have drawbacks, performance wise.

`SequenceEqual` implementation in  .Net Framework will not shortcut when the arrays have different lengths, and so it may enumerate one of them entirely, comparing each of its elements.
This said, depending on the .Net flavor (like .Net5), it may shortcut, see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232744/easiest-way-to-compare-arrays-in-c-sharp/3232755?noredirect=1#comment117533364_3232755). So for an up-to-date .Net project, `SequenceEqual` should be a good choice.

`IStructuralEquatable` is not generic and may cause boxing of each compared value. Moreover it is not very straightforward to use and already calls for coding some helper methods hiding it away.

It may be better, performance wise, to use something like:

```cs
bool ArrayEquals<T>(T[] first, T[] second)
{
    if (first == second)
        return true;
    if (first == null || second == null)
        return false;
    if (first.Length != second.Length)
        return false;
    for (var i = 0; i < first.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!first[i].Equals(second[i]))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But of course, that is not either some "magic way" of checking array equality.

So currently, no, there is not really an equivalent to Java `Arrays.equals()` in .Net.

Answer (score 2):

This LINQ solution works, not sure how it compares in performance to SequenceEquals. But it handles different array lengths and the .All will exit on the first item that is not equal without iterating through the whole array.

```
private static bool arraysEqual<T>(IList<T> arr1, IList<T> arr2)
        =>
            ReferenceEquals(arr1, arr2) || (
                arr1 != null && arr2 != null &&
                arr1.Count == arr2.Count &&
                arr1.Select((a, i) => arr2[i].Equals(a)).All(i => i)
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

elementwise compare ? what about

```
public void Linq78a()
{
 int[] numbers1 = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };
 int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };
 bool bb = numbers.Zip(numbers1, (a, b) => (a == b)).Any(p => !p);
 if (!bb) Console.WriteLine("Lists are equal (bb)");
   else Console.WriteLine("Lists are not equal (bb)");
}
```

Replace the (a==b) condition by anything you'd like to compare in a and b.

(this combines two examples from [MSDN developer Linq samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b))

Comment: It does not handle arrays of different lengths (may incorrectly yield `true`) and `null` arrays (will crash).

Answer (score 1):

I did this in visual studios and it worked perfectly; comparing arrays index by index with short this code.

```
private void compareButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int[] answer = { 1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 5, 4, 0, 6 };
            int[] exam = { 1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9, 5, 4, 0, 7 };

            int correctAnswers = 0;
            int wrongAnswers = 0;

            for (int index = 0; index < answer.Length; index++)
            {
                if (answer[index] == exam[index])
                {
                    correctAnswers += 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    wrongAnswers += 1;
                }
            }

            outputLabel.Text = ("The matching numbers are " + correctAnswers +
                "\n" + "The non matching numbers are " + wrongAnswers);
        }
```

the output will be; The matching numbers are 7
                    The non matching numbers are 3

Comment: It does not handle arrays of different lengths (will crash), `null` arrays (will crash too), and it does something else than what the OP asked. He only asked to know equality, without counting how many items differ or match.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking to determine if two sets had equivalent contents, in any order.  That meant that, for each element in set A there were equal numbers of elements with that value in both sets.  I wanted to account for duplicates (so `{1,2,2,3}` and `{1,2,3,3}` should not be considered "the same").

This is what I came up with (note that IsNullOrEmpty is another static extension method that returns true if the enumerable is null or has 0 elements):

```
    public static bool HasSameContentsAs<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> target) 
        where T : IComparable
    {
        //If our source is null or empty, then it's just a matter of whether or not the target is too
        if (source.IsNullOrEmpty())
            return target.IsNullOrEmpty();

        //Otherwise, if the target is null/emtpy, they can't be equal
        if (target.IsNullOrEmpty())
            return false;

        //Neither is null or empty, so we'll compare contents.  To account for multiples of 
        //a given value (ex. 1,2,2,3 and 1,1,2,3 are not equal) we'll group the first set
        foreach (var group in source.GroupBy(s => s))
        {
            //If there are a different number of elements in the target set, they don't match
            if (target.Count(t => t.Equals(group.Key)) != group.Count())
                return false;
        }

        //If we got this far, they have the same contents
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `array1.ToList().All(x => array2.Contains(x))` if you need to compare arrays which have not the same order

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow! This answer will not compare the arrays thoroughly, as it will return true if array1 contains [1], and array2 contains [1,2,3,4,5]. Other answers on this question related to using intersections answer it more thoroughly.

Comment: It would be correct if add `array1.Length == array2.Length`

Comment: @SergeiShvets, no that's also not true, because [1,1,1,1,2] and [1,2,2,2,2] would be equal according to your logic.

Comment: @hardfork agree, anything can't help this answer to work correctly

Answer (score 1):

[List Patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-11#list-patterns) is added in C#11 .Net 7 RC2.

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3 };

Console.WriteLine(numbers is [1, 2, 3]);  // True
Console.WriteLine(numbers is [1, 2, 4]);  // False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Enumerable.Intersect`:

```cs
int[] array1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4,5 },
      array2 = new int[] {7,8};

if (array1.Intersect(array2).Any())
    Console.WriteLine("matched");
else
    Console.WriteLine("not matched");
```

Comment: I do not think that this is what OP asks for. How does this compare the arrays? It only identifies, if the arrays have any common element. That's hardly an equivalent of Java `Arrays.equals()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to compare the order but you do want to compare the count of each item, including handling null values, then I've written an extension method for this.

It gives for example the following results:

```
new int?[]{  }.IgnoreOrderComparison(new int?{ });                            // true
new int?[]{ 1 }.IgnoreOrderComparison(new int?{ });                           // false
new int?[]{ }.IgnoreOrderComparison(new int?{ 1 });                           // false
new int?[]{ 1 }.IgnoreOrderComparison(new int?{ 1 });                         // true
new int?[]{ 1, 2 }.IgnoreOrderComparison(new int?{ 2, 1 });                   // true
new int?[]{ 1, 2, null }.IgnoreOrderComparison(new int?{ 2, 1 });             // false
new int?[]{ 1, 2, null }.IgnoreOrderComparison(new int?{ null, 2, 1 });       // true
new int?[]{ 1, 2, null, null }.IgnoreOrderComparison(new int?{ null, 2, 1 }); // false
new int?[]{ 2 }.IgnoreOrderComparison(new int?{ 2, 2 });                      // false
new int?[]{ 2, 2 }.IgnoreOrderComparison(new int?{ 2, 2 });                   // true
```

Here is the code:

```
public static class ArrayComparisonExtensions
{
    public static bool IgnoreOrderComparison<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second) =>
        IgnoreOrderComparison(first, second, EqualityComparer<TSource>.Default);

    public static bool IgnoreOrderComparison<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
    {
        var a = ToDictionary(first, out var firstNullCount);
        var b = ToDictionary(second, out var secondNullCount);

        if (a.Count != b.Count)
            return false;

        if (firstNullCount != secondNullCount)
            return false;

        foreach (var item in a)
        {
            if (b.TryGetValue(item.Key, out var count) && item.Value == count)
                continue;
            return false;
        }


        return true;

        Dictionary<TSource, int> ToDictionary(IEnumerable<TSource> items, out int nullCount)
        {
            nullCount = 0;
            var result = new Dictionary<TSource, int>(comparer);
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                if (item is null)
                    nullCount++;
                else if (result.TryGetValue(item, out var count))
                    result[item] = count + 1;
                else
                    result[item] = 1;
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

It only enumerates each enumerable once, but it does create a dictionary for each enumerable and iterates those once too. I'd be interested in ways to improve this.

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361054/check-if-two-list-have-the-same-items) which converts one of the array to a `HashSet` and uses `SetEquals` for comparison with the other array.
Note however that this does not check for order or duplicates.

Answer (score -2):

```
        int[] a = { 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2 };

        int[] b = { 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2 };

        bool ans = true;

        if(a.Length != b.Length)
        {
            ans = false;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                if( a[i] != b[i])
                {
                    ans = false;
                }
            }
        }

        string str = "";

        if(ans == true)
        {
            str = "Two Arrays are Equal";
        }

        if (ans == false)
        {
            str = "Two Arrays are not Equal";
        }

       //--------------Or You can write One line of Code-------------

        var ArrayEquals = a.SequenceEqual(b);   // returns true
```

Comment: That's quite suboptimal. You should stop the comparison on the first non-matching element. + This answer does not show anything that is not covered in the existing answers already.