# How to compare arrays in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, compare

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easiest way to compare arrays in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232744/easiest-way-to-compare-arrays-in-c-sharp)

How can I compare two arrays in C#?

I use the following code, but its result is false. I was expecting it to be true.

```
Array.Equals(childe1,grandFatherNode);
```

Comment: Could you give us an example?

Answer (score 286):

You can use the Enumerable.SequenceEqual() in the System.Linq to compare the contents in the array

```
bool isEqual = Enumerable.SequenceEqual(target1, target2);
```

Comment: Great answer, and I know it's a little late, but that could be simplified to this:
    bool isEqual = target1.SequenceEqual(target2);

Comment: AMing solution handle null cases (and is more 'symmetric').

Comment: @Orace: actually, Enumerable.SequenceEqual gives an exception if either argument is null.

Comment: `Enumerable.SequenceEqual(x, y)` and `x.SequenceEqual(y)` behave the same way: they throw `ArgumentNullException` if first or second collection is null. Just look at [implementation on Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,0c673d96d87461e6).

Comment: For a quick explanation: `x.SequenceEqual` is an extension method so it's the exact same as calling `Enumerable.SequenceEqual`. Thus the behavior regarding null inputs will be the same no matter which way you write the call

Comment: Make sure to import `System.Linq` before using `Enumerable.SequenceEqual`

Comment: @ConnieHilarides please check this as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/74321055/6527049

Answer (score 48):

You're comparing the **object references**, and they are not the same. You need to compare the array contents.

### .NET2 solution

An option is iterating through the array elements and call `Equals()` for each element. Remember that you need to override the `Equals()` method for the array elements, if they are not the same object reference.

An alternative is using this generic method to compare two generic arrays:

```
static bool ArraysEqual<T>(T[] a1, T[] a2)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(a1, a2))
        return true;

    if (a1 == null || a2 == null)
        return false;

    if (a1.Length != a2.Length)
        return false;

    var comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    for (int i = 0; i < a1.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!comparer.Equals(a1[i], a2[i])) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

### .NET 3.5 or higher solution

Or use [SequenceEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) if Linq is available for you (.NET Framework >= 3.5)

Comment: my arrays is Multidimensional and SequenceEqual not work for this type

Comment: @madhi: You can extend the method to receive T[][] instead T[]. Have you considered mark the question as aswered? Thanks!!

Answer (score 25):

There is no static `Equals` method in the `Array` class, so what you are using is actually `Object.Equals`, which determines if the two object references point to the same object.

If you want to check if the arrays contains the same items in the same order, you can use the `SequenceEquals` extension method:

```
childe1.SequenceEqual(grandFatherNode)
```

#### Edit:

To use `SequenceEquals` with multidimensional arrays, you can use an extension to enumerate them. Here is an extension to enumerate a two dimensional array:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(this T[,] items) {
  for (int i = 0; i < items.GetLength(0); i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < items.GetLength(1); j++)
      yield return items[i, j];
}
```

Usage:

```
childe1.Flatten().SequenceEqual(grandFatherNode.Flatten())
```

If your array has more dimensions than two, you would need an extension that supports that number of dimensions. If the number of dimensions varies, you would need a bit more complex code to loop a variable number of dimensions.

You would of course first make sure that the number of dimensions and the size of the dimensions of the arrays match, before comparing the contents of the arrays.

#### Edit 2:

Turns out that you can use the `OfType<T>` method to flatten an array, as RobertS pointed out. Naturally that only works if all the items can actually be cast to the same type, but that is usually the case if you can compare them anyway. Example:

```
childe1.OfType<Person>().SequenceEqual(grandFatherNode.OfType<Person>())
```

Comment: my array is Multidimensional and this method not work on it !

Comment: @mahdi: You can use a simple extensions to make a multi dimensional array enumerable. I added an example above.

Comment: @Trisped: The `Flatten` method doesn't create any new array, it's just a way to access the array as a one dimensional enumerable.

Comment: @Mark: No, it's not wrong. I wrote explicitly in the answer: *"You would of course first make sure that the number of dimensions and the size of the dimensions of the arrays match, before comparing the contents of the arrays."*

Comment: You can just use `OfType<T>` to flatten a multidimensional array. No need to create a new extension method.

Answer (score 13):

`Array.Equals` is comparing the references, not their contents:

> Currently, when you compare two arrays with the = operator, we are really using the System.Object's = operator, which only compares the instances. (i.e. this uses reference equality, so it will only be true if both arrays points to the exact same instance)

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/kathykam/array-equals)

If you want to compare the *contents* of the arrays you need to loop though the arrays and compare the elements.

The same blog post has examples of how to do this. The basic implementation is:

```
public static bool ArrayEquals<T>(T[] a, T[] b)
{
    if (a.Length != b.Length)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!a[i].Equals(b[i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Though this will have performance issues. Adding a constraint:

```
public static bool ArrayEquals<T>(T[] a, T[] b) where T: IEquatable<T>
```

will improve things but will mean the code only works with types that implement `IEquatable`.

Using EqualityComparer.Default's Equal method instead of calling Equals on the types themselves will also improve performance without requiring the type to implement `IEquatable`. In this case the body of the method becomes:

```
    EqualityComparer<T> comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!comparer.Equals(a[i], b[i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Equals` method does a reference comparison - if the arrays are *different* objects, this will indeed return false.

To check if the arrays contain identical values (and in the same order), you will need to iterate over them and test equality on each.

Answer (score 0):

Array.Equals() appears to only test for the same instance.

There doesn't appear to be a method that compares the values but it would be very easy to write.

Just compare the lengths, if not equal, return false. Otherwise, loop through each value in the array and determine if they match.