# how to compare arrays in c# without knowing their types

Tags: arrays, c#-4.0, types

I am having 2 class objects.of same class. It having int string double types of arrays. Where as I need to compare these properties with another object of same class. I need generic approach to compare identical properties regardless of knowing types.

Comment: This can help...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423318/how-to-compare-arrays-in-c

Comment: Do you have a code snippet you could share?