# Dictionary key not working as a type of Tuple<int[], int>

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a situation where I would need a dictionary with this type of key, but it doesn't seem to find the equivalent key later on.

```
Dictionary<Tuple<int[], int>, object> cache = new Dictionary<Tuple<int[], int>, object>();

cache.Add(Tuple.Create(new int[]{1}, 1), new object());

Assert.That(cache.ContainsKey(Tuple.Create(new int[] { 1 }, 1))); // This fails
```

I've tested it by using a `Tuple<int, int>` and it seems to be working fine, but in my case I really need some sort of `Tuple<int[], int>` and with that type of key, it doesn't work.

Is there any other alternative to this that would be working?

Comment: So what is your error?

Comment: The problem is that I can't lookup in my dicco with that type of tuple

Comment: well that's because you can't compare arrays that way as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423318/how-to-compare-arrays-in-c)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Arrays are not comparable. For example:

```
var array1 = new int[] { 1 };
var array2 = new int[] { 1 };
Debug.WriteLine(array1 == array2); // this returns false
Debug.WriteLine(Object.Equals(array1, array2)) // this returns false
```

You need to do one of two things:

1) Replace `int[]` with a custom class that implements the necessary `Equals` and `GetHashCode` overrides.

2) Write a class that implements `IEqualityComparer<Tuple<int[], int>>`. That class will provide the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods for `Tuple<int[], int>`s. Provide an instance of that class to your `Dictionary<Tuple<int[], int>, object>`

Answer (score 0):

You can not compare array with `==` You [can use this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713341/comparing-arrays-in-c-sharp):

```
 static bool ArraysEqual<T>(T[] array1, T[] array2)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(array1,array2))
            return true;

        if (array1 == null || array2 == null)
            return false;

        if (array1.Length != array2.Length)
            return false;

        EqualityComparer<T> comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!comparer.Equals(array1[i], array2[i])) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```