# Is there any risk making a base class generic and then making a class that inherits from it not generic? (which also has children classes)

Tags: c#

Please see the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class GenericClass<T> where T: class,new()
    {
        public virtual bool Equals(T other)
        {
            if (other == null)
                return false;
            Type t = GetType();
            Type otherType = other.GetType();
            if (t != otherType)
                return false;
            FieldInfo[] fields = t.GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
            foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
            {
                object value1 = field.GetValue(other);
                object value2 = field.GetValue(this);
                if (value1 == null)
                {
                    if (value2 != null)
                       return false;
                }
                else if (!value1.Equals(value2))
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    public class Animal : GenericClass<Animal>
    {
    }

    public class Dog : Animal
    {
        public string Name;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dog d1 = new Dog();
            Dog d2 = new Dog();
            d1.Name= "Patch";
            d2.Name = "Patch";
            d1.Equals(d2);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that Dog is using the .Equals method in the GenericClass.  The code works as I want it to i.e. GenericClass compares Dog1 to Dog2.

However, notice that the Animal class is not a generic class.  Is there any risk doing this? Should I be making Animal generic for some reason?

Comment: Easy answer: No. The derived class doesn't need to be generic unless there's some reason why it needs to be.

Comment: @Ed Plunkett, thanks.  Could you elaborate and provide the long answer? (or point me to a link?)

Comment: If a class needs to be generic, make it so. "The base class was generic" by itself isn't such a reason. There isn't a long answer. In fact, one of the classic use cases for a generic class is "base class for ten similar classes that do the same thing with different concrete types".

Comment: @Ed Plunkett, is it fair to say that if Animal does not use any generic parameters, then it does not need to be generic in this case.

Comment: Yes. That's entirely fair to say -- your `Sub : Base<Sub>` pattern is another classic use case for a generic class, which just about always has a non-generic subclass (and see Eric's answer)

Comment: Inheriting from a generic class into a non-generic one differs from a very common practice of implementing a generic interface in a non-generic class only by your ability to inherit/override some implementation. This is completely safe.

Comment: 3 close votes? I found this question and Mr. Lippert's answer quite insightful.

Comment: @SamPearson: I don't see any reason why this question is being closed as "opinion based"; it's a crisp yes-or-no question and the answer is no. (Also, Mr. Lippert is my father, dude.)

Comment: @EricLippert then I guess you should cast a reopen vote (now there is none).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, notice that the Animal class is not a generic class. Is there any risk doing this?

Nope.

> Should I be making Animal generic for some reason?

Nope.

A question you did not ask but should have:

> Is abusing generics and reflection to make a generalized-equality base class a good idea?

Nope.

- The implementation is crazy, in that `dog1.Equals((object)dog2)` and `dog1.Equals(dog2)` can give opposite results. This is a bug waiting to happen.
- If we don't fix the bug then the equality check is by value for the animals being compared, but by reference for any animal properties, and so crazy and wrong. If we do fix the bug then the implementation goes into infinite recursion if the network of objects contains a cycle.
- If the author of `Animal` wants to implement `IEquatable<Animal>`, they're free to do so using their own semantics. This is solving a general problem that is easier to solve specifically.
- You only get once chance at a base class. Make it count. You get zero benefits of polymorphism with this choice of base class. You get a benefit of sharing code that could be achieved just as well by making an extension method or other library method.
- The assumption that two instances are value-equal if all their fields are value-equal is false.

The larger takeaway here is: **implementing value equality is surprisingly difficult in C#**. You've got to be *really* careful to make sure that you're comparing the right things, not going into infinite recursions, and making your hashcode implementation match. This argues against one-size-fits-all attempts.

Comment: Thanks.  I am trying to do something like this for my value types: https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2007/06/25/generic-value-object-equality/.  Is this something you wouldn't recommend when applying DDD principles? A different author here seems to suggest the same thing: https://github.com/vkhorikov/DddInAction/blob/master/DddInPractice.Logic/Common/ValueObject.cs +1 for the "question you should of asked".

Comment: But this implementation seems not recursive at all - how it can get into infinite recursion?

Comment: @w0051977: First: I would not ever recommend wasting your one chance on inheritance on such a useless base class. Again: if you want objects to implement `IEquatable<T>` then make objects implement `IEquatable<T>`. If you want to share implementation details **make the implementations call a library method**.

Comment: Second: the implementation in the second link is both more principled and more useless; it makes the good requirement that the derived class provide a sequence of (probably boxed!) objects from which equality is derived. So think about that: **if the derived class author has to go to that work, they're doing almost same amount of work they had to do to simply implement value equality in the first place**.

Comment: @Evk: We must fix the bug that `Equals(object)` and `Equals(T)` are different. Consider: `class Cat : Animal { public Cat parent; public Cat child; public override bool Equals(object x) { return this.Equals(x as Cat); }` ... `Cat c1 = new Cat(); Cat c2 = new Cat(); c1.child = c2; c2.parent = c1; bool b = c1.Equals(c2);` goes into an infinite recursion.

Comment: @Evk: Now, if we *don't* fix the bug then the code is wrong in another way.  If we have `class Tiger : Animal { public string name; public Tiger mother; }` and `Tiger t1 = new Tiger() { name = "Teri"; }; Tiger t2 = new Tiger() { name = "Teri"; }; Tiger t3 = new Tiger() { name = "Toni"; mother=t1 }; Tiger t4 = new Tiger() { name = "Toni"; mother=t2; }` then we have the bizarre situation of `t4.mother.Equals(t3.mother)` true and `t1.Equals(t2)` true, but `t4.Equals(t3)` false.  Fix the bug and we get a crash; don't fix the bug and we get crazy results. The solution is: abandon this bad code.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of overriding `object.Equals` and call another `Equals` there. Yes I completely agree with your answer, just with a quick look didn't see how infinite recursion is possible (I mean, what should I do, however stupid, to make it happen).

Comment: @Evk: It was not at all obvious from my answer; I'll clarify the text.

Comment: @Eric Lippert, thanks.  I agree with you.  I believe my requirement is exactly what IEquatable is for.  Is your answer relevant to a Domain Driven Design context as well? The reason I ask is because I have seen a few more with apps on GitHub with a generic ValueObject base class.

Comment: @w0051977: I am not familiar with the dogma of domain driven design. I was under the impression that the central idea of DDD was *cleanly map concepts from the business domain in the program domain*.  I can accept that as a good principle. So **what concept in the business domain of dogs and cats does your `GenericClass<T>` map to**?  Because I have never once looked at my cat and thought "my cat is an animal, and an animal is a `GenericClass` of animal".

Comment: @w0051977: The base class here seems to not be at all in the semantic domain of the business, but rather *entirely in the domain of program mechanisms*. I have never once thought "I wonder if my cat and this other cat are equal? I know; I'll reflect over their properties and recursively compare their values."  If the base class is not in the business domain at all then what principle of DDD justifies its existence?

Comment: Thanks.  In my domain model ValueObject is the base types, which all value objects derive from.  The ValueObject class looks the same as the class in the two links I provided in an earlier question.

Comment: @w0051977: Sure, I accept that you've derived stuff from "ValueObject". My question to you is: what principle of DDD suggests that the program-mechanism-concern of how objects are compared for equality should be included in the class hierarchy? My extremely weak understanding of DDD is that DDD encourages the opposite of that. We should be modeling characteristics of the business domain in the type hierarchy.

Comment: @w0051977: Also, what is so special about *comparison by value*?  I could also write a generic base class for *T can be collated into a sensible order in a list of T*.  I could also write a generic base class for *a T can be combined with another T to form a third T*.  Are these also concerns in DDD?  If yes, and if the right way to do this is by inheritance, then *how on earth would we represent a type that can be compared for equality, collated, and combined*?  You only get one base class in C#.

Comment: Interesting that this implementation seems to be copied from `ValueType.Equals` implementation, probably that's why people who originally created it thought it's a good one to use. After all, struct is more or less similar to DDD value object.

Comment: @Evk: The irony of course is that the `ValueType.Equals` implementation is widely considered to be pretty lousy. In common cases it is fast but inaccurate or slow and expensive.  The delivered wisdom from the design guidelines is that *structs which are intended to be compared by value should implement bespoke equality methods rather than relying on the default Equals*. Copying a bad implementation is just bad. Making it a *base class* is a waste of an opportunity for inheritance.

Comment: @Eric Lippert, there is no concept of a ValueObject in the business domain.  Therefore I think I am going to remove it.  I will try the iequatable idea tomorrow and then come back to mark the answer.