# Logical error while creating Palindrome Program

Tags: c#

I tried to make Palindrome program as small as possible. However, this program is giving logical error. When I enter palindrome string it gives "False" as result which is opposite of what is expected.

```
char[] phrase;
Console.WriteLine((phrase = Console.ReadLine().ToArray())==phrase.Reverse().ToArray());
Console.ReadLine();
```

I do not want to increase number of statements of this program.

Comment: Irrespective of it man..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you created 2 different array and arrays are *reference type*, `==` checks for *reference equality*, not value.

You can use [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead which returns;

> **true** if the two source sequences are of equal length and their
>   corresponding elements are equal according to the default equality
>   comparer for their type;

```
Console.WriteLine(myString.SequenceEqual(myString.Reverse()));
```

- [Easiest way to compare arrays in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232744/easiest-way-to-compare-arrays-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 5):

In .NET, arrays do not have an overloaded equality operator. Use `Enumerable.SequenceEquals`.

Reading your code more thoroughly, you are making things more complicated than necessary.

```
    string phrase = Console.ReadLine();
    var reversedPhrase = phrase.Reverse(); //Type is IEnumerable<char>
    Console.WriteLine(phrase.SequenceEquals(reversedPhrase));
```

I recommend that you don't burry side-effects inside of expressions in the way you did. That code could well have been a test question to see if a student can work it out.

Comment: It almost certainly is a test question.

Comment: @usr Your answer is incorrect, it is still giving False for a Palindrome string. I have solved the problem through SequenceEqual

Comment: @usr No, man, `string.Reverse()` returns "System.Linq.Enumerable+<ReverseIterator>. I have solved it throught EnumerableSequence and it works perfect.. Anyways thanks for help..

Comment: Hm, string seems to have no Reverse method. Where did I get that idea from.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it by array then you can try this

```
char[] phrase;
Console.WriteLine(phrase = Console.ReadLine().ToArray().SequenceEqual(phrase.Reverse().ToArray()));
Console.ReadLine();
```

just like usr said use [sequenceequal](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sequenceequal)