# What interface to implement to compare Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, compare

I have a custom class that contains a string.  My program has an array of these classes and I want to be able to compare one array of these to another.

I have implemented the IComparable interface as described here:
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25352&seqNum=4 but I find that this does not allow me to compare one array against another. (It allows me to sort the array)

```
public class MyClass : IComparable<MyClass>
    {
        #region Private
        private string _name;
        #endregion

        #region Public

        [XmlElement("Name")]
        public string Name
        {
            get{return _name;}
            set{_name= value;}
        }
        #endregion

        public int CompareTo(MyClass class)
        {
            string s1 = this.Name;
            string s2 = class.Name;
            return String.Compare(s1, s2);
        }

        override public string ToString()
        {
            return _name;
        }
    }
```

My program has an array of these classes like so:

```
MyClass class1 = new MyClass();
class1.Name = "a";

MyClass class2 = new MyClass();
class2.Name = "b";

MyClass class3 = new MyClass();
class3.Name = "c";

MyClass class4 = new MyClass();
class4.Name = "d";

MyClass[] classes1 = { class1, class2, class3}
MyClass[] classes2 = { class1, class2, class4};
```

I can sort the class if need be:

```
Array.Sort(classes2);
```

What interface do I need to implement to allow me to compare one array against another to see if they are equal?

**EDIT**
My class is custom and does not inherit from any interfaces so I want to know what interface to implement, how to implement it and how to use it.  This example uses objects which are not custom: [Easiest way to compare arrays in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232744/easiest-way-to-compare-arrays-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were referring to sorting, not comparing :-P

Comment: You create a comparer for the array in exactly the same way that you create the comparer for the single object.  You create the comparer, and write whatever you want in the `Compare` method.  What problem(s) did you have implementing that?

Answer (score 0):

Your class needs to override the [Equals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx) method.
Alternatively, you can implement the [IEquatable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx) interface.
You can then apply the "[SequenceEquals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567(v=vs.110).aspx)" LINQ Operator to your arrays in order to achieve what you desire.