# C# CollectionAssert.Contains (int[][], int[]) does not pass

Tags: c#, arrays, unit-testing

The function I want to test returns an `int[][] aaiCluster1` with data

```
aaiCluster1[0] = int[] { 1, 2 }
aaiCluster1[1] = int[] { 0 }
```

so I test using

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual (aaiCluster1[0], new int[] { 1, 2 });
CollectionAssert.AreEqual (aaiCluster1[1], new int[] { 0 });
```

But the order of the `int[]` is not important and may change, so I rather want to test

```
CollectionAssert.Contains (aaiCluster1, new int[] { 1, 2 });
```

but this fails.
Is this command not able to evaluate the content of the array?
Any ideas for a suitable workaround, that does not require additional helper functions?

**edit**
I have to clarify:
*it's about testing whether a jagged array contains another simple array **nested** in it.*
**What else must I explain??**

**edit #2**
2 answers suggesting `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent` were given already and have been deleted again, because `AreEquivalent` is not what I'm looking for... it does not work here.
1 answer suggesting `Sequence.whatever` was given, and it's even more wrong.

---

**edit #3**
I reverted Igor's changes to my question, because I feel they too much alter the meaning. However, I think his words are a good alternative describtion, so here is his text:

So I test using

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new int[] { 1, 2 }, aaiCluster1[0]);
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new int[] { 0 }, aaiCluster1[1]);
```

But the order in `aaiCluster1` (actual) is not known so the above tests could fail as soon as the returned order in `aaiCluster1` changes.

**Question**

How can I call something similar to this

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new int[] { 1, 2 }, aaiCluster1);
// CollectionAssert.AreEqual(ICollection<T> expected, ICollection<ICollection<T>> actual);
```

where all arrays in `aaiCluster1` are evaluated against the expected parameter `new int[] { 1, 2 }` and the assert passes if there is at least one contained array that is found to be Equal to the expected?

Comment: dupliacated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232744/easiest-way-to-compare-arrays-in-c-sharp

Comment: There exists `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent` which ignores the order.

Comment: @Dongdong: no, it's not a duplicate of that. That's something completely different.

Comment: @Dongdong `SequenceEquals` (which is the propsed answer in your mentioned duplicate) takes the order into account, what the OP doesn´t want.

Comment: take a look the answer from @Harry He  in that post.

Comment: @Dongdong: yes, and like I said this is something entirely different.

Comment: @TobiasKnauss See my answer, that should work assuming there are no duplicates

Comment: @johnny5 He doesn't want helper functions.

Comment: I'm out somones got a vendetta against this question too many downvotes going around

Comment: @TobiasKnauss good point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
aaiCluster1.ContainsArray(new int[] { 1, 2 });

static class Extensions
{
    public static bool ItemsEqual<TSource>(this TSource[] array1, TSource[] array2)
    {
        if (array1 == null && array2 == null)
            return true;
        if (array1 == null || array2 == null)
            return false;
        return array1.Count() == array2.Count() && !array1.Except(array2).Any();
    }

    public static bool ContainsArray<TSource>(this TSource[][] array1, TSource[] array2)
    {
        return array1.Any(x => x.ItemsEqual(array2));
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, and this looks pretty much like what I need. However, you just could have mentioned that I need a helper function. I was looking for a solution without one, but obviously there isn't any.

Comment: if Microsoft implement everything, your company won't need you any more. Microsoft provided `extensions` to extend base class, you should fall in love with it, but not against it. you could add this extension to same namespace with CollectionAssert, then you will see: the extension look like a kind of official method..

Comment: @TobiasKnauss, I'd say this is the most complete correct answer so far, the only addition which could be made would be to handle duplicates, but that can be done with a group by

Comment: @Dongdong: true. I just thought there was a built-in function for such a case. But obviously my situation is too rare to be handled by Microsoft.

Comment: they implement base only, but for real world project, we have to add thousands of extension, that's the real value of us.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make sure the on set fully contains another you can just use linq, Assuming there are no duplicates you can do this:

```
Assert.IsTrue(new int[] { 1, 2 }.Except(aaiCluster1[0]).Count() == 0);
```

Comment: you use `aaiCluster1[0]`, but I don't want to reference a specific index.