# How to return true when comparing arrays with same items but in random positions?

Tags: c#, arrays, compare

Compare two arrays.
Return true if first array has same items as second array, even if they are in different positions.
Here are two possible arrays:

```
int[] arrayA = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] arrayB = { 3, 2, 1 };
```

I can only find if arrayB has a single number in arrayA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easiest way to compare arrays in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232744/easiest-way-to-compare-arrays-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a built-in method to compare collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500/is-there-a-built-in-method-to-compare-collections)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [SequenceEqual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal) method (LINQ).

```
bool areEqual = arrayA.OrderBy(n => n).SequenceEqual(arrayB.OrderBy(n => n));
```

Comment: This is more expensive than `arrayA.ToHashSet().SetEquals(arrayB)`.

Comment: @canton7 it may be more expensive, but it is still preferable because it produces correct results. Instead `set1.SetEquals(set2)` will erroneous report that the arrays { 1, 2, 1 } and { 1, 2, 2 } are equal, because it ignores duplicate elements.

Comment: Very true. There are ways around this which use a Dictionary, and also don't require that your items are comparable.

Comment: @canton7 agreed.

Comment: @canton7 you may want to provide a performant and correct implementation using Dictionaries. I have already offered an answer, and I think it's not right to offer a second one.

Comment: See duplicates, like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098/comparing-two-collections-for-equality-irrespective-of-the-order-of-items-in-the

Comment: @canton7 yeap, you are correct. I forgot it's a duplicate question. :-)

Answer (score 0):

One method to solve this would be create a `HashSet<int>` from each array, then use `.SetEquals(HashSet<int> hashSet)` to check if they have the same values.

```
public static bool CompareArrays(int[] array1, int[] array2)
{
    // Create sets using Linq
    HashSet<int> set1 = array1.ToHashSet();
    HashSet<int> set2 = array2.ToHashSet();
    // Compare the sets with .SetEquals()
    return set1.SetEquals(set2);
}
```

Comment: `set2` doesn't need to be a `HashSet` -- `HashSet<T>.SetEquals` takes an `IEnumerable<T>`.