# Is it possible to test an entire array at once?

Tags: c#, arrays, if-statement

Is there a way to use an if statement to test an entire array at once by doing something like this:

```
if(myArray == {1,2,3})
{Debug.Log("This is quick")}
```

or do I need to iterate through each value in the array like this:

```
if(myArray[0] == 1 && myArray[1] == 2 && myArray[2] == 3)
{Debug.Log("This is not as quick")}
```

Comment: You could use SequenceEquals

Comment: Or take a look at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232744/easiest-way-to-compare-arrays-in-c-sharp)...

Comment: SequenceEqual does the trick. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 1):

You should use [SequenceEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx).

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int [] myArray = {1,2,3};
        int [] myArray2 = {1,2,4};

        bool result = myArray.SequenceEqual(myArray2);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution and made my life a lot easier. Thanks!