# Why doesn't Distinct (Linq) work in a List of int[]?

Tags: c#, linq, distinct

I wrote this method. It's supposed to return all triplets [a, b, c] from an array of integers for which a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 = c ^ 2.

```
public static List<int[]> AllTripletsThatFulfilla2b2c2Equality(int[] n)
    {
        var combinations = from i in n
                           from j in n
                           from p in n
                           select new int[][] {new int[]{ i, j, p }, new int[] {p, j, i}, new int[] {i, p, j}};
        
        return combinations.Where(x => x.Length == x.Distinct().Count() && Math.Pow(x[0], 2) + Math.Pow(x[1], 2) == Math.Pow(x[2], 2)).Distinct().ToList();
    }
```

Distinct doesn't work.

I've tried several other ways to write this, including

```
public static List<int[]> AllTripletsThatFulfilla2b2c2Equality(int[] n)
    {
        var combinations = from i in n
                           from j in n
                           from p in n
                           select new[] { i, j, p };
        combinations = combinations.ToList();
        Func<int[], List<int[]>> combo = x =>
        {
            List<int[]> list = new List<int[]>();
            list.Add(x);
            if (!combinations.Contains(new [] { x[0], x[2], x[1] }))
            {
                list.Add(new[] { x[0], x[2], x[1] });
            }


            if (!combinations.Contains(new[] { x[2], x[1], x[0] }))
            {
                list.Add(new[] { x[2], x[1], x[0] });
            }
            list.Add(new [] { x[0], x[2], x[1] });
            list.Add(new [] { x[2], x[1], x[0] });
            return list;
        };

        return combinations.SelectMany(combo).Distinct().Where(x => x.Length == x.Distinct().Count() && Math.Pow(x[0], 2) + Math.Pow(x[1], 2) == Math.Pow(x[2], 2)).ToList();
    }
```

and even added a comparer for Distinct:

```
        public class TripletComparer : IEqualityComparer<int[]>
    {
        public bool Equals(int[] x, int[] y)
        {
            return x[0] == y[0] && x[1] == y[1] && x[2] == y[2];
        }

        public int GetHashCode(int[] obj)
        {
            return obj.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Same result when tested, this one:

```
Assert.Equal() Failure
Expected: List<Int32[]> [[3, 4, 5], [4, 3, 5]]
Actual:   List<Int32[]> [[3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5], [4, 3, 5], [4, 3, 5], [4, 3, 5], ...]
```

Somehow, it doesn't see that there are items that repeat themselves. Does anyone have any idea why, and how to fix it?

Comment: because there is no overloaded comparsion and default check only if it's the same object (same point in the memory)

Comment: @Selvin okay, do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I mean you need to use `Distinct<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, IEqualityComparer<TSource>)` and pass `IEqualityComparer<int[]>` to point what do you mean when you are saying that `int[]` is equal to another `int[]`

Comment: Look into the duplicate, in particular this answer, if you can´t (or dont want to) change the class: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1365761/2528063

Comment: and additional resource https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232744/easiest-way-to-compare-arrays-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Selvin How does this link help? OP needs to provide some means for equality anyway, no matter if he´s using `Distinct` or `SequenceEquals`.

Comment: I can´t see where you provide an instance of the equality-comparer to `Distinct`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere with *provide some means for equality* for `int[]`

Comment: your `GetHashCode`-implementation seems odd. Usually you compute a hashcode based on the exact same members you use within the actual `Equals`-check.

Comment: @HimBromBeere fixed GetHashCode, it worked, thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `GetHashCode`-implementation seems odd. Usually you compute a hashcode based on the exact same members you use within the actual `Equals`-check. Otherwise `Distinct` will probably not even call into your `Equals`-method.

```
public bool Equals(int[] x, int[] y)
{
    return x[0] == y[0] && x[1] == y[1] && x[2] == y[2];
}

public int GetHashCode(int[] obj)
{
    int hash = 17;
    // Suitable nullity checks etc, of course :)
    hash = hash * 23 + obj[0].GetHashCode();
    hash = hash * 23 + obj[1].GetHashCode();
    hash = hash * 23 + obj[2].GetHashCode();
    return hash;
}
```

Disclaimer: the hashcode-code is adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/2528063.