# Compare Arrays in C# using SequenceEqual

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, generics, equality

I am trying to compare two arrays in C# as posted in previous SO post:

- [Easiest way to compare arrays in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232744/easiest-way-to-compare-arrays-in-c-sharp)

Why is the following not working for me:

```
var first = Value as Array;
var second = other.Value as Array;
bool equal = first.SequenceEqual(second);
```

I get:

> CS1061: 'Array' does not contain a definition for 'SequenceEqual' and
> no accessible extension method 'Array' accepting a first argument of
> type 'Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
> assembly reference?).

I do have the right using at the top:

```
using System.Linq;
```

since I can write (no compiler error):

```
var first = Value as string[];
var second = other.Value as string[];
bool equal = first.SequenceEqual(second);
```

For reference, I am trying to implement the `Equals` operator for a generic value type:

```
public struct MyValue<T> : IEquatable<MyValue<T>> 
{
  public T Value { get; set; }
  public bool Equals(VRValue<T> other) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: `Array` implements `IEnumerable`, but `SequenceEqual` is only defined for `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: Rather than checking for `Array`, a better way could be to check for [`IStructuralEquatable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.istructuralequatable?view=net-5.0), which `Array` (and a few other collections) implements.

Comment: You can use Linq with an `Array` by casting its elements, e.g. `bool equal = first.Cast<object>().SequenceEqual(second.Cast<object>());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @Sweeper/@Jeppe Stig Nielsen suggestions, I rewrote my function as:

```
public bool Equals(VRValue<T> other)
{
    if (typeof(T).IsArray)
    {
        var first = Value as IStructuralEquatable;
        var second = other.Value as IStructuralEquatable;
        return StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.Equals(first, second);
    }
  [...]
}
```

When using a HashSet, one should also pay attention to GetHashCode:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    if (typeof(T).IsArray)
    {
        var first = Value as IStructuralEquatable;
        return StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.GetHashCode(first);
    }
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Consider `return StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.Equals(first, second);`. (What you have now, is just checking for sameness (i.e. reference equality), so it is equivalent to `return first == second;` which will say false if the two operands are distinct arrays with identical lengths and identical entries.)

Comment: For "get hash code" you must use the relevant method, not just some other one! So certainly `return StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.GetHashCode(first);` now that you follow my suggestion from the first comment. Hash codes should match the `Equals` used, or else all is nonsense. `EqualityComparer<object>.Default` is really wrong in your case.

Answer (score 2):

`SequenceEqual` works with `IEnumerable<T>`, but `Array` implements only non-generic `IEnumerable`, so `SequenceEqual` does not applicable here.

When casting to the `string[]`, you got different (typed) type of array, which exactly implements `IEnumerable<T>` (where T is string for this sample)